# What building was mentioned in the following paragraph.: 如果單看設計圖的話，這棟大樓倒是和漢字六有點相似，不過中間的方形更像正方形。

Tags: place-names

What is this buildings name.:

準確的來說，這是一棟集政務院，眾議院和國家法院為一體的大型建築。

如果單看設計圖的話，這棟大樓倒是和漢字六有點相似，不過中間的方形更像正方形。

Comment: Could 漢字六 mean "漢字中的六字"?

Comment: The posted text comes from a novel: https://www.69shuba.com/txt/47770/34468698

Comment: The title of the novel is "澳洲崛起录".

Comment: There is no mention of the name of the building in the text given. It just describes what the building looks like, but it sounds untrue because as far as I know there is not a 口 in the Chinese character 六.

Answer (score 1):

The passage you refer to is from The Book of [澳洲崛起录](https://www.qidian.com/chapter/1035813221/763783747/) by author `疯艺炯龙`.

Due to copyright issues, the details of this post of the novel should be viewed at the [site](https://www.69shuba.com/txt/47770/34468698) provided by  [@user2249675](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/28949/user2249675).

Here are some more details:

> 准确的来说，这是一栋集政务院，众议院和国家法院为一体的大型建筑。
>
> 如果单看设计图的话，这栋大楼倒是和汉字六有点相似，不过中间的方形更像正方形。
>
> 政务院，众议院和国家法院三个不同直属的机构，分别部署在六的三个点。
>
> 中间的正方形建筑则是大型会议室，会客室，对外开放区域等所在。
>
> 这样由四处建筑合起来的六字形建筑，加上其附带的建筑区域和园林面积，共同构成了这座新的国家政府所在。

---

about `漢(汉)字六`:

`六` belongs to [hieroglyphics](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B1%A1%E5%BD%A2%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97).

The original meaning of `六` is cottage, which is the original writing form of the Chinese character `庐`. `庐` and `六` are similar in ancient pronunciation, so `六` is disguised as the numeral "six".[[1]](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%AD/1896293?fr=ge_ala)

The stroke of the word `六` is following.

[image]

---

Given the context of the novel, the author does not indicate that the building mentioned in the paragraph is a building in the real world.

Based on the author's Chinese identity and my understanding of Chinese architecture, the layout of the building mentioned in the article is similar to [Beijing Daxing International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing_Daxing_International_Airport).

The image below is an aerial view of it.

[image]

Its layout is similar to `大`, and the written form of `大` is roughly the same as `六`.

---

The following is the layout of the building that I have created by myself, based on the structure of `六` and the author's description in the novel.

[image]

Comment: I think your answer as a whole is great, especially your last option.  However I don't think the airport is this type and I think it only adds confusion to include it.  I recommend removing it.  Just the red and green lines themselves are good.